# What target environment should I use to compile android Camera app code?

Tags: java, android, unix, android-sdk-2.1

I am a .NEt developer but recently i am having to deal with some android /java code. I downloaded Android OS's camera app source code from following location:

> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera

Now, I am having these files on my Windows 7 machine. When I do a simple search of "How to compile android apk code on windows" most of the searches result in saying that it is very non trivial and I need Mac or Unix machine for it.

Now, Looks like this is all bunch of java files. But I am not sure what should b emy target environment to try to compile all these files?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the SDK tools? http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Download adt bundle [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. Extract the zip and start ecllipse ide
3. Create a new emulator on which you run your application. It looks like a mobile icon.
4. then goto file->import->android->existing android project to workspace
5. Browse to your downloaded location select your project
6. Run